# How am I meant to use npm js packages on my site when the sauce files are in node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Sorry if this is a basic question. I want to use JS packages like Lite Youtube Embed (https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-youtube-embed).

I understand how to download the files with NPM, but then the istructions say to include the files as such `<script src="node_modules/lite-youtube-embed/src/lite-yt-embed.js"></script>` straight from `node_modules`.

Considering I (and I assume many others) don't deploy `node_modules` to a live site, how are you actually meant to use these pacakges?

Comment: You can use gulp to copy files that you want from node_modules to your project root during the build process. Or use webpack. Or use unpkg.com

Comment: you usually have a build or dist etc script that copies the files you need from node_modules to your public dir. But you only do that if the script isn't already on something like cdnjs.com (which is not the case here), or something like unpkg.com is not an option.